# Windows 8 : Unalbe to find dll file

Tags: dll

I am running a utility. When running i got this error.Even i copied the msys-1.0.dll in system32. Also tried to register it but unable to do that also.

---

### sed.exe - System Error

### The program can't start because msys-1.0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

### OK

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the link given below and Download  msys-1.0.dll file

https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/msys_1_0_dll.html

Answer (score 0):

Msys-1.0.dll is a type of DLL file associated with Realsoft3D developed by Linux Format for the Windows Operating System. The latest known version of Msys-1.0.dll is 1.0.0.0, which was produced for Windows.
Reasons of error maybe:

1. Invalid or corrupt msys-1.0.dll registry entry.
2. Virus or malware infection which has corrupted the msys-1.0.dll
   file.
3. Linux Format hardware failure, such as a bad hard drive, which has
   corrupted the msys-1.0.dll file.
4. Another program maliciously or mistakenly deleted the msys-1.0.dll
   file.

**FIX:**
see [here](http://www.dllmissing.com/fix-missing-or-not-found-msys-1.0.dll-errors-129017)